# Use rules to convert unix timestamp to number of days

Tags: views, rules

I have two date fields. The standard Drupal 7 "Content: Post date" and "Content: Updated date" fields.

I want to calculate the difference in day's between those two date fields and update a third field with the calculated value in the same node when the node is updated.

*Here is my Current Rule*

*(Convert first date field to Unix Time)*

```
Convert data type    
Parameter: Target type: Integer, Value to convert: [node:created]    
Provides variables: Date Created (date_created)
```

*(Convert second date field to Unix Time)*

```
Convert data type    
Parameter: Target type: Integer, Value to convert: [node:changed]    
Provides variables: Date Changed (date_changed)
```

*(Subtract the two timestamps from one another to get the number of seconds between each)*

```
Calculate a value       
Parameter: Input value 1: [date-changed], Operator: ( - ), Input value 2: [date-created]    
Provides variables: Calculate Days (calculate_days)
```

*(Divide calculated timestamp by the number of seconds in a day to get the number of days)*

```
Calculate a value    
Parameter: Input value 1: [calculate-days-variable], Operator: ( / ), Input value 2: 86400    
Provides variables: Calculate Days in Seconds (calculate_days_in_seconds)
```

*(Convert the value to an integer and round to get a whole number (if needed))*

```
Convert data type    
Parameter: Target type: Integer, Value to convert: [calculate-days-in-seconds], Rounding behavior: Always up (9.5 -> 10)    
Provides variables: Conversion result (conversion_result)
```

*(Add Calculaton to custom field)*

```
Set a data value    
Parameter: Data: [node:field-days], Value: [calculate-days-variable]
```

The output from this rule seems to be correct and is giveing me "166349"
which is 1 days, 22 hours, 12 minutes and 29 seconds.

What I am trying to do now is figure out how to convert that number "166349"  to the number of days which in this case should be 2 days when it is rounded up.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with the tag about the "computed field" module?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I forgot to remove that tag when I made my edit. Thanks

Comment: Aha, that makes (way) more sense ... Let the answers flow ...

Comment: i added this answer in a similar question here [diff in days betwen two dates and store data in a third field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253197/how-to-show-a-users-age-at-the-time-of-creating-a-node-in-a-view), i hope it helps.